# Happy New year 2020

Tags: discussion

I drop in to wish a happy new year to the community ! :)

A small image for it in the spirit of SF :)

[image]

Edit, a good image that fit the spirit of MSE :P (j/k, but the message is nice anyhow :) )

[image]

Edit2; a good’s one too :)

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! Happy New Year !